# Cannot merge .txt files having different encoding in Python

Tags: python, xml, merge, ascii

I'm trying to merge a number of .txt files into one file. Some of the files are plain text .txt files I created in advance, while some are files written by the script itself. The script successfully merges some of the files (the ones I wrote in advance) but does not include the ones created by the script, even though it raises no error. It literally seems to ignore their existence.

I have tried different methods, including `shutil` and `fileinput`, and even using `cat` from `subprocess.call` but without luck.

From the terminal, the files I created in advance are "XML document text" (though I actually saved it as plain text, but it is formatted as XML), while the other ones are "ASCII text". I believe this is the problem, as the XML ones were .rtf files, and they wouldn't merge before I converted them – only the first of the list would be included in the output file.

```
import os, itertools, subprocess, fileinput, shutil

os.chdir('/Users/MicTonutti/Dropbox/MRes/Individual Project/FEBio/Simulation')

forces = itertools.permutations([-1.5,-1,-0.5,0],3)
forces = list(forces)
force_node = 174

for i in range(0,len(forces)):
    filename = '0_Insert' + str(i) + '.txt'
    f = open(filename, 'w')
    string_x = '<nodal_load bc="x" lc="2"> <node id="' + str(force_node) + '">' + str(forces[i][1]) + '</node> </nodal_load>\n'
    string_y = '<nodal_load bc="y" lc="2"> <node id="' + str(force_node) + '">' + str(forces[i][2]) + '</node> </nodal_load>\n'
    string_z = '<nodal_load bc="z" lc="2"> <node id="' + str(force_node) + '">' + str(forces[i][2]) + '</node> </nodal_load>\n'
    f.write(string_x + string_y + string_z)

filename_2 = '1_Insert' + str(i) + '.txt'
g = open(filename_2, 'w')
string_1 = '<logfile>\n <node_data data="x;y;z" file = "coord_data' + str(i) + '.txt" delim=", "> </node_data>\n'
string_2 = '<node_data data="ux;uy;uz" file = "displacement_data' + str(i) + '.txt" delim=", "> </node_data>\n </logfile>\n'
g.write(string_1 + string_2)

files_list = ['Simulation 1.txt', filename, 'Simulation 2.txt', filename_2, 'Simulation 3.txt']
output_file = '/Users/MicTonutti/Dropbox/MRes/Individual Project/FEBio/Simulation/Python Output/FEBio Simulation Output' + str(i) + '.txt'

with open(output_file, 'w') as outfile:
    for infile in files_list:
        shutil.copyfileobj(open(infile), outfile)
```

The output basically looks like this:

Text of "Simulation1.txt" + Text of "Simulation2.txt + Text of "Simulation3.txt", without the files in the middle. 
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `flush()` on the files you write before you try to read them again, else the written data might still be buffered.

Apart from that I wanted to point out that you write to 24 different `0_Insert` files in your loop (`0_Insert1.txt` to `0_Insert23.txt`), but later on only read from the last one. Is this what you actually are trying to do? Or should your loop also include the bottom part of your code?

Comment: Yes, sorry – my code got formatted wrong once I copy-pasted it. The for loop includes everything until the end.

Anyways, flush() works perfectly! Thanks so much.